# XPath: Find element with most text content

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

I want to look for paragraphs. I would use the p tag to look for this but I've seen pages that don't use p when they should. To approximate this, I just want to look for the most text in one tag. Any ideas how to find this

Comment: You'll have to be careful. I think the most text will be between the `<html>` and `</html>` tags.

Comment: You could parse every element on the tree and obtain the content of each as a string, then just count the characters in the string.

Comment: I think text_content() only returns the non-html text. I'm not sure how I could use something like it with an XPath expression though

Comment: But once I've found the correct element, I'm not sure what attribute to use to check the type of tag. I'll need to know the type of tag (and the class) so I can estimate where the text is for the next page.

Comment: @user1136342 did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `//div/node()[string-length(following-sibling::node()/text()) < string-length(text())]`

Actually that's only covering one direction, use this one:

```
//div/node()[string-length(following-sibling::node()/text()) < string-length(./text()) and not(string-length(preceding-sibling::node()/text()) > string-length(./text()))]
```

I was using some scrap xml to test this, and the root was `<div>` so change that to the xml root you're examining.